# Adapter repeating values on if condition in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Hi `stackoverflow` I'm really wondering why `Adapter` repeats the stuff when we put `if` condition inside the `Adapter`, please someone guide me to correct my mistakes, here is my `adapter`

```
public class CustomStoreAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
/** Variable declaration */
private ArrayList<StoresUtility> storeList = new ArrayList<StoresUtility>();
private Context context;

public CustomStoreAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}// End of CustomAdapter constructor

public void setData(ArrayList<StoresUtility> serviceProviderList) {
    this.storeList = serviceProviderList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getCount() {
    return storeList.size();
}// End of getCount method

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return storeList.get(position);
}// End of getItem method

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}// End of getItemId method

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.stores_adapter, null);
    }// End of if block

    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_store_full_name);
    TextView firstLetter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_store_first_letter);
    TextView mobileOne = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_store_one);
    TextView mobileTwo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_store_two);

    LinearLayout llOne = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_mobie_one);
    LinearLayout llTwo = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_mobie_two);

    RelativeLayout rlOne = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl_contact_store_one);
    RelativeLayout rlTwo = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl_contact_store_two);

    try {
        if(storeList.get(position).getName().length() > 0) {
            char initial = storeList.get(position).getName().charAt(0);
            firstLetter.setText(""+initial);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { }

    name.setText(""+storeList.get(position).getName());

    if(!storeList.get(position).getMobileOne().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        llOne.setVisibility(0);
        mobileOne.setText(""+storeList.get(position).getMobileOne());
    }

    if(!storeList.get(position).getMobileTwo().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        llTwo.setVisibility(0);
        mobileTwo.setText(""+storeList.get(position).getMobileTwo());
    }

    return v;
}// End of getView method
}//End of CustomServiceAdapter class
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem happened for [Recycle ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

you need change :

```
if(!storeList.get(position).getMobileOne().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        llOne.setVisibility(0);
        mobileOne.setText(""+storeList.get(position).getMobileOne());
    }

    if(!storeList.get(position).getMobileTwo().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        llTwo.setVisibility(0);
        mobileTwo.setText(""+storeList.get(position).getMobileTwo());
    }
```

to

```
if(!storeList.get(position).getMobileOne().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        llOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mobileOne.setText(""+storeList.get(position).getMobileOne());
    }
else
     llOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if(!storeList.get(position).getMobileTwo().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        llTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mobileTwo.setText(""+storeList.get(position).getMobileTwo());
    }
else
   llTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and please don't use `0` for changing visibility of your view to Visible, instead of `0` use `View.VISIBLE`

Comment: Wow Great answer @Shayan pourvatan +1 and accepted. Will you please tell me why not `0` for Visible ?

Comment: do not use literal integers , that is bad habit, use View.GONE or View.VISIBLE instead integer number, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) for more info